# Is there any free resource to get international raster data (other than USGS)?

Tags: raster, data

I am looking for any raster database that allows free downloads of any kind of raster data pertaining to Damascus, Syria and the surrounding Turkey area. I'm trying to avoid USGS since it requires a lengthy sign-up.

I am open to any site that would allow me to query for data based on that location and extract it for free without too much of a sign up process. I don't care if its DEM, topology, orthography, lidar, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check out http://www.terrainmap.com/rm39.html i hope it will help.

**More specific:**

http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/Index.asp

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need a high resolution you could have a look at: [naturalearthdata.com](http://www.naturalearthdata.com)

Comment: yeah I've looked at naturalearthdata, but I mainly wanted data for that specific location.

Answer (score 0):

You can check http://gdex.cr.usgs.gov/gdex/ 
i hope it will helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

You can get DEM's from [CGIAR](http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/Index.asp) via an an line download tool